# How use jquery accordion in MVC5 View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I try to use #accordion (jquery) in my MVC5 view even thought I tried several ways to add the reference to Jquery files, I m getting this error:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'accordion'
```

this is my view:

```
@model CSAProject.Models.CustomerModel
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")"    type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui.css")"  type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


 <style>

   body {
   font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
font-size: 62.5%;
  }
   </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
      $("#accordion").accordion();
  });
  </script>
  <div id="accordion">
  <h3 style="color:#009AE1">Customer Profile</h3>
 <div>
 test 
 </div>
 <h3 style="color:#009AE1">Payment</h3>
 <div>
 test2
</div>
<h3 style="color:#009AE1">Password</h3>
  <div>
  test3
  </div>
   </div>
```

I am getting error right in this line:

```
  $("#accordion").accordion();
```

Comment: You need to include the `jquery` library _before_ the `jquery-ui` library.  And you're including the CSS as a script, not a stylesheet.

Comment: You also need to wrap the script in `document.ready()` or place it at the bottom of the page

Comment: @ jmoerdyk it is not working with these changes as well. It is working in a regular HTML page but when I put code in the mvc view I get error.

Comment: I suggest opening developer tools (F12) after loading your page to ensure that the scripts are loading correctly. If your code works in an html page, but not with razor, something is probably wrong with your paths.

Comment: @esmoore68 I am sure it is nor loading Jquery ui. in the html page I am using references like this  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: but even when I use this in MVC view is not working. I even used three  way explained here :http://blog.falafel.com/three-steps-use-jquery-ui-asp-net-mvc-5/ but still not loading it. I have installed the JqueryUI in NuGet too.

Comment: Can you update your original post to show how the script is called after you added the "document.ready()" code?

Answer (score 0):

Its clear that you have an issue with the order in which dependencies are being loaded. Why are you including these in views? You should put these in the bundle configuration. Putting these links in the body makes the browser load the js libraries before the page has finished loading and lots of issues - bundle config prevents that.

Open the file `~/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs`and put the links there. That way, you can make sure that all the dependencies are being rendered in the correct order:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                             "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                             "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js",
                             "~/Scripts/MyApp/MyCustomJS.js"));
```

And then make 'MyCustomJS.js' contain:

```
$(function () {
      $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

don't fall into the trap of putting stray javascript into views because when you use the bundleconfig it actually reads everything and minifies it before sending it to the browser, and then outputs it at the bottom of the page. Putting it in the views means that it will be read before the minified javascript is even rendered